# Invalid object name 'ApexSQL.ApexSQL_SourceControl.Objects'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, source-control

I was trialing Apex source control - trial ended. Uninstalled Apex (well I thought I did). Today I deleted the Apex database. Now I get

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ApexSQL_SourceControl_DDLTrigger, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 7]
Invalid object name 'ApexSQL.ApexSQL_SourceControl.Objects'.
```

Can not find any triggers at all on the server - how can I get rid of this error. Won't let me alter any procedures.

Comment: This returns no results? `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT DB_NAME() as [database], * FROM ?.sys.triggers'`

Answer (score 3):

Found it  - under linked servers triggers.

Comment: If you are like me and did not create a dedicated DB, the trigger you are looking for is in:
Programmability -> Database Triggers -> ApexSQL_SourceControl_DDLTrigger